# Trouble with Windows 10 upgrade to 64-bit asking for PtrSafe attribute?

Tags: vba

I am having trouble with the following a declaration statement as below:

```vb
Private Declare Function WNetGetUser Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetUserA" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpUserName As String, lpnLength As Long) As Long
```

The error is asking for a `PtrSafe` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my typo - I have now found the statement that was not working and included PtrSafe and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Declaration, please:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WNetGetUser Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetUserA" _
          (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpUserName As String, lpnLength As Long) As Long
```

And use the next function to retrieve the logged user name:

```
Function GetUserName() As String
 Const lpnLength As Long = 255
 Dim status As Long, lpName, lpUserName As String

 'Assign the buffer size constant to lpUserName.
 lpUserName = Space$(lpnLength + 1)

 status = WNetGetUser(lpName, lpUserName, lpnLength)

 'See whether error occurred.
 If status = 0 Then
    lpUserName = Left$(lpUserName, InStr(lpUserName, Chr(0)) - 1)
 End If

 GetUserName = lpUserName
End Function
```

It can be called:

```
Sub TestUserName()
    Debug.Print GetUserName
End Sub
```

All above, only if you insist to use API...

But VBA has its simple way of obtaining it:

```
Debug.Print Application.UserName
```

If you not like it, using VBScript (in VBA) may help:

```
Sub testUserNameVBSCript()
 Dim userName As String
   userName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").userName
   Debug.Print userName
End Sub
```